# VertX: download files from server

Tags: download, vert.x

I want to open the browser built-in pop-up to download a file when going to this url?

http://localhost:8080/retrieval

Now on the server side I have:

```
router.get("/retrieval").handler(rc -> {
        rc.response().sendFile("J1.txt");
    });
```

Instead I see the content of the file in the browser. What should I do? Is there some specific headers that need to be sent?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I found out :)

The solution is as I thought using some headers:

```
rc.response()
        .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain")
        .putHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"J1.txt\"")
        .putHeader(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING, "chunked")
        .sendFile("J1.txt").end();
```